# How to download scripts.retrain for TensorFlow for poets to?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda

I tried to run the training for my AI in anaconda but I didn't work.

I tried to follow [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#3) tutorial, but when I used this command:

```
python -m scripts.retrain \--bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \--how_many_training_steps=500 \--model_dir=tf_files/models/ \--summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \--output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \--output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \--architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \--image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

I got the message:

> "  "No module named scripts.retrain"

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone to the following repository?

```
git clone https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2
```